# export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH" needed for every single command

Tags: bashrc, nano

so I was trying to set JAVA_HOME variable and some how I ended up facing this error every time I want to use terminal

```
Command 'poweroff' is available in the following places
* /sbin/poweroff
* /usr/sbin/poweroff
The command could not be located because '/sbin:/usr/sbin' is not included in the 
PATH environment variable.
This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative privileges associated with 
your user account.
poweroff: command not found
```

I can fix it with this command:

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

but every time I open new terminal I face the error again and I have to use this command again.

I would appreciate it if you could help.
by the way I use `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your home directory, edit .bashrc

Add your line:

> export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"

Now your path will be exported every time you start a new terminal instance.

You can, of course, add any other path you want, before $PATH

Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Although, since you accepted the [question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1434239/558158), it may be a stopgap that works for you, the better approach would be to fix the cause of the error. Unfortunately, in your question, you do not indicate *how* you set the `JAVA_HOME` variable. Somehow, you made changes somewhere that empty the `PATH` variable.

Thus, carefully inspect your `.bashrc` file. Anything that changes the `PATH` was added by yourself. By default, the `PATH` is not anymore modified in `.bashrc`. See `/etc/skel/.bashrc` for a default `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 2):

The `PATH` is typically set in `/etc/environment`. Here's my version:

```
$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
```

Now, I don't know what you did to set your `JAVA_HOME`, but there are some examples like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013303/ubuntu-java-environment-path-bash-etc-environment-permission-denied which explain how to add `JAVA_HOME` to `/etc/environment`. If you followed this, but replaced the `>>` by a `>`, instead of adding to the existing file, you overwrote it. Which means the `PATH` is missing now.

Re-adding the `PATH` definition from my example should fix most issues, unless you have some package installed that adds yet another path component.

The advantage of doing this in `/etc/environment`, instead of `.profile` or `.bashrc`, is that it works for all users, including users that run server processes, instead of just for you.